# Dart - how to use reflection to wrap all Stream methods?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create a Stream class wrapper, that will work like this:

```
class MyCustomStream extends Stream {
}

class StreamWrapper extends MyCustomStream {
    Stream? stream;
    StreamWrapper(): super() {
        stream = this.asBroadcastStream()
    }

    // all Stream methods should be delegated to the this.stream.methodName()  
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this delegation (related only to Stream methods, the MyCusomStream methods should stay as they are) using reflection?

Or do I have to write all Stream's methods by hand?

Answer (score 1):

The `Stream` class is fairly simple in that regard because almost all the methods use the exact same implementation everywhere.

All you need to do is to forward the `listen` method:

```dart
class StreamWrapper<T> extends MyCustomStream<T> {
  final Stream<T> _stream;
  StreamWrapper(Stream<T> source) : _stream = source.asBroadcastStream();
  bool get isBroadcast => true;
  StreamSubscription<T> listen(void Function(T)? onData, {
    Function? onError, void Function()? onDone, 
    bool? cancelOnError}) =>
    _stream.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone,
        cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
}
```

I pass in the stream to wrap as a parameter, because otherwise the `this` stream reference becomes cyclically depending on the `stream` value.

All the methods inherited from `Stream` will just call `listen`, and that is forwarded to `_stream` with this.

Comment: This is fine, but only in the case of BroadcastStream. It would be much more complicated if I needed to use map() on _stream. That's why I was asking about a generic solution to delegate all stream methods.